# Unable to scroll a vertical scrollbar attached to a div

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a webkit scrollbar attached to a div. I have disabled the default scrollbar by setting the overflow property to hidden, in the body element. I can see the scrollbar which is attached to the div, but cannot see its thumb, and hence also not able to scroll. The div to which scrollbar is attached has id="container". Here is the css -

```
html
{
}    
body 
{
   overflow-y:hidden;
   overflow-x:hidden;
}

#container
{ 
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#Title
{

   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

table
{
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed; 
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar
{
   background: transparent;
   width: 12px;
} 

#container::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(10,11,12,0.3);
  /*  border-radius: 10px; */
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
{
    border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background:rgba(104,102,102,0.8);
}
```

The container hosts a div (with id="Title"), and a table. The table has lot of content, so scrolling should happen, but unfortunately it doesn't. If someone could please point out what am I doing wrong, that would be great. Thanks!

Edited : Adding the html -

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="Title">
   <span id="Heading_part_1">abc</span>
   <span id="Heading_part_2">xyz</span>
   <span id="Heading_part_3">pqr</span>
   <span id="Timestamp"></span>
   <span id="WrenchIconContainer" onclick="togglemenu();">
       <input type="image" src="res/wrench-arrow-icon.png" width="18px" height="18px"/>
   </span>
   <div id="menu_container" style="display:none">
       <p id="id1">sfdf</p><p id="id2" onclick="dosomething();">ffsdf</p>
   </div>
</div>
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th id = "headline" width="85%"></th>
    <th id = "storytime" width="15%"></th>
</tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could we take a look at the HTML File also?

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/FFMxb/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `#container` has a height of 100%, the scrollbar "thumb" has no reason to appear because container is actually big enough to fit the entirety of its contents. If you give it a fixed, pixel height, your "thumb" will appear and function beautifully. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/FFMxb/).

If you wrap your container with yet another wrapper and give it `position: relative;` you can leave your container with a 100% height, but add

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

If what you're really trying to do is replace the main browser scroll bar for the page, just replace `#container` with body for your `::-webkit-scrollbar`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`, and `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` selectors.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I am actually using this webpage inside an iframe, which will be hosted under a parent div. This particular parent div will be constantly resized at runtime. So I cannot keep a static fixed height of container div in pixels. Any pointers on how to make this thing work in such a scenario? Simply modifying the container height at runtime based on resizing of parent hosting the iframe is not working.